# ArgumentError: Error #1508: The value specified for argument font is invalid

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, external

I have an air application that loads an external swf when prompted by the user. In the external swf, I have a class that loads all the necessary fonts for that particular swf. When my air application attempts to load the swf I get **ArgumentError: Error #1508: The value specified for argument font is invalid.** Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to not load any font libraries the external swf used and opted to use fonts loaded at runtime with the main application.